# Is it possible to set link attributes using UIAppearance on TTTAttributedLabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

I'm tying to create a `TTTAttributedLabel` wrapper in order to provide UIAppearance support for `linkAttributes` and `activeLinkAttributes` properties among other stuff (i.e custom links)

As the interface

```
@interface MYLabel : TTTAttributedLabel

@property (strong, readwrite, nonatomic) NSString *richText;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *dataTextAttributes UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; //Default: text color blue
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *selectedDataTextAttributes UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR; //Default: text color red

@end
```

As the implementation

```
@implementation MYLabel

// .. some code

- (void)setDataTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)dataTextAttributes {
    _dataTextAttributes = dataTextAttributes;
    self.linkAttributes = dataTextAttributes;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setSelectedDataTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)selectedDataTextAttributes {
    _selectedDataTextAttributes = selectedDataTextAttributes;
    self.activeLinkAttributes = selectedDataTextAttributes;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}

// .. some code

@end
```

The problem is the setters are being called by the proxy after I add some links manually using:

```
[label addLinkToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"action://defaultAction"] withRange:result.range]
```

So happens that links are not getting the correct stlye unless I reuse a label i,e: on a table view cell.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

BTW: If I set the properties manually, it works.